# newtx math italic font replaced by Nimbus font. Should this happen?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, newtx, substitution

I'm running the newtx package under TexLive 2016 and finding that the math italic font (ntxmi expected, OML encoding under the .sty file) is being replaced by a UWR/nimbus font (utmri8a). All other fonts seem fine. Not sure why this is?

Details: 
pdflatex under TexShop 3.75 with TexLive 2016, Mac OS Sierra

```
newtxtext.sty    2016/08/12 v1.5
omlntxmi.fd      2015/08/25 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OML/ntxmi.
newtxmath.sty    2016/11/18 v1.514


\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbfit}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it} % for comparison
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$h\,x\,d$ % results in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb 

$\mathbfit{h\,x\,d}$ % results in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/newtx/rntxbmi.pfb

$\mathbf{h\,x\,d}$ % results in usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qtmb.pfb>

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font used for `\textfont1` (the characters in the first formula) is

```
\OML/ntxmi/m/it/10.95
```

that maps to `ntxmi at 10.95pt`. Here's the start of the output when we do `vftovp ntxmi.vf`:

```
(VTITLE )
(FAMILY UNSPECIFIED)
(FACE F MRR)
(CODINGSCHEME TEX MATH ITALIC)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 34425111214)
(SEVENBITSAFEFLAG TRUE)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.277)
   (SPACE R 0.0)
   (STRETCH R 0.0)
   (SHRINK R 0.0)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.441)
   (QUAD R 1.0)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME txmi)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 5432341673)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME rntxmi)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 11446214367)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
```

By looking at the rest of the output and searching for `SELECTFONT D 1`, we realize that the font `rntxmi` is used for the digits, *g*, *v*, *w*, *y* and octal 176 (the arrow for `\vec`). So the main font `txmi` is used for the rest. Now let's do `vftovp txmi.vf`:

```
(VTITLE )
(FAMILY TXMI)
(FACE F MRR)
(CODINGSCHEME FONTSPECIFIC + CMMIENCODING)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 5432341673)
(SEVENBITSAFEFLAG TRUE)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.277)
   (SPACE R 0.0)
   (STRETCH R 0.0)
   (SHRINK R 0.0)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.441)
   (QUAD R 1.0)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME rtxmi)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 12672155070)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME rtxptmri)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 16356635626)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )

[...]

(CHARACTER C A
   (CHARWD R 0.636)
   (CHARHT R 0.6535)
   (COMMENT
      (KRN O 177 R 0.111)
      )
   (MAP
      (MOVERIGHT R 0.025)
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR C A)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER C B
   (CHARWD R 0.636)
   (CHARHT R 0.6535)
   (COMMENT
      (KRN O 177 R 0.058)
      )
   (MAP
      (MOVERIGHT R 0.035)
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR C B)
      )
   )

[...]
```

The font `rtxptmri` is used for the letters, which is our case. Now, here's the entry for this font in `pdftex.map`:

```
rtxptmri NimbusRomNo9L-ReguItal " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <utmri8a.pfb
```

So, yes: math italic letters in the `newtxmath` font are taken from a font that is realized with “Nimbus Roman No9 Regular Italic”, except for the above mentioned letters. Indeed, running `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

$gvwy$

\end{document}
```

results in this output from `pdffonts`:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
WKGQAX+rntxmi                        Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
```

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, for this clear and complete answer!  After some further investigation, I suppose this should not be a surprise, given that the Gyres Termes font (the text font of newtx) is itself derived from the Nimbus set, as mentioned at http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/termes.